# decrease the Android API level during app update

Tags: android, google-play, android-manifest, apk

I have an Android app already published on Google Play and my manifest.xml has these fields declared:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   package="xxxxxx"
   android:versionCode="4"
   android:versionName="1.3" >

    <uses-sdk
       android:minSdkVersion="14"
       android:targetSdkVersion="18" 
       />
```

In this version I'm using a specific library to do something that can works only to 18 API version.
The problem is: I added new features to my app and I want update it on google market but I want to exclude API 19, so I modified my manifest.xml in this way:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="xxxxxx"
    android:versionCode="5"
    android:versionName="1.4" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="14"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" 
        android:maxSdkVersion="18"/>
```

I uploaded my app but I have some errors like:

> Can not publish the configuration for the following reasons:  A device
>   that are upgrading from levels in the range of 14-18 API to API levels
>   in the range of 19 + can not be downgraded from version 5 to version
>   4. The error occurs in the following cases:  Trace output with a more of the following: [ALPHA] and  Layout screen with a more of the
>   following: [small, normal, large, xlarge] and  Functions with all of
>   the following: [android.hardware.screen.PORTRAIT,
>   android.hardware.TELEPHONY, android.hardware.TOUCHSCREEN].  Some
>   devices are suitable for running multiple APK. In this scenario, the
>   device will receive the APK with the highest version number.

Any solutions?
Thank you.
Marco

Comment: Firstly, `android:maxSdkVersion` was deprecated a long time ago and is seriously discouraged - I didn't even realise Google Play took any notice of it any more. Second, why do you want to exclude API 19+?

Comment: Because I'm using a not public API to use SSL client certificate and it doesn't work on KitKat. Is there any workaround to set the max sdk version?Thanks

Comment: "Is there any workaround to set the max sdk version?" : No and it's not really how Android is designed to work which is why its use is deprecated. Basically what you've done is released your `versionCode 4` app making it available to all devices using API 4 and above. Now you're trying to publish your `versionCode 5` app but restricting it to devices which may already have it installed (anything running API 19+) - this is why you're having problems. I suggest you contact the author of the SSL library you're using and persuade them to update to support API 19.

Comment: I tried to contact the author of the SSL library but no answer. I don't know how can i I do to solve it.

Comment: Sorry, I can't help. Find another library which works with API 19 written by people who actively support it.

Comment: I tried to find out something similar but no much topic about this and the people point to this library as the solution.